# Why do these two identical view counts have different colors?

Tags: support, design, views

I was browsing popular questions on Code Review Stack Exchange and I stumbled upon this disparity:

[image: View Counts Image]

What causes this behavior to happen? If both questions are above 10k views, shouldn't they both be orange?

[Link to questions](http://web.archive.org/save/https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tab=month)

Comment: Note: that link *will* become useless over time.

Comment: Worth noting that the tooltip on the view count says 10343 for the top one and 9921 for the bottom one. So the top one is over 10k but the bottom one below and as the bottom one is the same colour as the other <10k one, it is a safe bet that the colour changes at more than 10k views and the bottom one is just rounded up.

Comment: I’ve included this information in [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336810/4642212).

Comment: It's nice to know that there's a justification for a design bug, but it's still a bug. Naturally, coloration should take rounding into account and "hot" color should be used for posts with 9500+ views.

Comment: The color should be smoothly interpolated, using a [diverging color map](https://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-maps/).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The orange one has (when I'm writing this) 10,343 views, above the 10k threshold for the orange color. You can see this by hovering over the view count.
The brown one has 'only' 9,921 views, so it doesn't qualify.